# htaccess redirect for new parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I have some old link like `website.com/pages.php?d=7`.But now i have change the scripts with new parameter like `website.com/pages.php?d=7&s=200`

looking for a way to redirect the old link to new one

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /pages\.php\?d=7 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?s=200 [L,QSA,R=301 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if `s=200` is always same, then you can rewrite it. Else its not possible to rewrite from 
`website.com/pages.php?d=7` to `website.com/pages.php?d=7&s=200`. You have to pass the `name=>value` pair some way or the other if you want it to be available for processing.

if `s=200` is a constant put this in the `.htacces` in `DocumentRoot` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/pages\.php\?d=7$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?s=200 [QSA,L,R=301]
```